# Properties by reflection

Tags: c#, properties, subclass, entities

how can access sub class properties?, I can access Y properties, in this case Name, but not x, another case is the same but instead of single reference of x, with a list of x, in this second case how iterate every object.

```
    public class X
{
    public int ID{get;set;} 
    public int Name{get;set;}
}

public class y
{

    public string Name{get;set;}
    public x Reference{get:set;}
}

    //second case 
public class y
{

    public string Name{get;set;}
    public List<x> Reference{get:set;}
}



public static void Main()
{
    y classY = new y();
    y.Name = "some text here";
    y.x.ID = "1";
    y.x.Name ="some text for x here";
}

// in another class, pass y
// so, in this method I only can get 'y' values, but not x
Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
public void GetProperties(object p)
{
    Type mytype = p.GetType();
    var properties = mytype.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        table.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(p, null));
    }   
}
```

#### UPDATE

Also try with interface

```
public interface ISub
{}
public class X : ISub // etc....


if (typeof(ISub).IsAssignableFrom(property.GetType()) ) // this alwas as false
```

Comment: You want to obtain properties only for used types defined in your assembly? How would you handle it if `y` had a reference to `x` and `x` had a property of type `y`?

Comment: Because the object's contains descendant reference,

Answer (score 0):

You will have to evaluate each property to know if it is a list or not:

```
foreach (var prop in properties)
{
    var obj = prop.GetValue(p, null);
    if (obj is List<x>)
    {
        var list = obj as List<x>;
        // do something with your list
    }
    else
    {
        table.Add(prop.Name, obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is useful for the list, but i really don't know how drill down through objects